# Count 1 column of 2 without condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to count the content of one column, which is no problem.
But also i want to count another column content but with a where condition.

I visualize it for better explaining:

My table

```
Index1       Index2
1            0
1            2
2            2
2            2
2            2
```

now i want to count the content of Index1 that i know how often the numbers 1 and 2 appears.
But further i want to count the content of Index2, but only the numbers which are higher than 1.

Result

```
Index1       amount
1            1
2            3
```

but when i use the `where` condition it is used for both columns.
I tried it with distinct but it doesn´t work.

Are there some comfortable solutions for this problem?

Comment: would you please add your query to question as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's called conditional aggregation, and in MySQL it's pretty simple :

```
SELECT t.index1,
       COUNT(*) as amount
       SUM(t.index2>1) as amountWithWhere
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY t.index1
```